# Toggle triangle ► ▲ on dropdown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What would be the best way to toggle ► triangle to ▲ on dropdown (without using images)?

```
<div class="box-heading">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="switch-filters">
          <span>►</span> Možnosti filtrovania</a>
</div>

    $( "#switch-filters" ).click(function() {
    $(".filter_group[filtertype!='p']").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Yes, we can do it for you and no, you won't have a bad reputation on your #newUser account.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and define the triangle in CSS3 with the pseudo tag `:before`

**CSS**

```
.box-heading > a:before{
   content: "▲";
}

.box-heading > a.active:before{
   content: "►";
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".box-heading > a").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("active")
});
```

Comment: 1+ I like this suggestion.

Comment: Haha I was just making a fiddle for something like this. +1 :-D

Answer (score 3):

you could use CSS.. so when you click on the a tag, you add a class to the a tag.. say a class called **clicked** and then have a CSS rule associated with that class

```
a.clicked span {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(90deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
        /* transform for IE8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
        zoom:1;
}
```

then CSS will rotate the span 90 degrees making the left arrow become a down arrow

browser compatibility

http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

also link to **CSS Matrix Rotation Calculator**:

http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

:)

Comment: that's a fun idea :) you need toggleClass on top, though. And one could add some animation (transition) - would certainly look cool!

Comment: Just to mention, this is css-level-3 and not fully supported for a 'cross-browser' solution.

Comment: @MilchePatern It gets to a point where you have to stop worrying about support. Just use CSS3..

Comment: @MilchePatern here is the browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

Comment: Well, according to 'Caniuse.com' only IE10+, IE-mobile and Firefox23+ supports the CSS3. All the others are prefixed proprietary non-css3. Maybe we should not stop worrying too fast about that ?

Comment: CSS **transform** property will work in all latest modern browsers, without a prefix.. the above will work in all browsers even crappy ie8.. which is there until Microsoft stops support for XP in April 2014

Answer (score 1):

Use a Ternary expression

```
$(".filter_group[filtertype!='p']").is(":visible") ? $(this).next("span").text("▲") : $(this).next("span").text("►")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to replace the html of your span

Something like :

```
$('span').text('▲');
```